# Cypher query not returning all expected pathways

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I set up a simple example for myself to see how Neo4j handles queries involving nodes that have relationships with themselves, and I cannot get Cypher to give me all pathways.

Here's my data:

```
CREATE (A {name:'A'}), (B {name:'B'}), (C {name:'C'})
CREATE 
   (A)-[:REL]->(A),
   (A)-[:REL]->(B),
   (A)-[:REL]->(C),
   (B)-[:REL]->(A),
   (B)-[:REL]->(B),
   (B)-[:REL]->(C),
   (C)-[:REL]->(A),
   (C)-[:REL]->(B),
   (C)-[:REL]->(C)
```

And here's the query I'm doing:

```
MATCH p = (x)-[:REL*1..3]->(y) 
WHERE x.name='A' AND y.name='B' AND LENGTH(p) = 3 
RETURN nodes(p)
```

My expected results are:

```
A, A, A, B
A, A, B, B
A, A, C, B
A, B, A, B
A, B, B, B
A, B, C, B
A, C, A, B
A, C, B, B
A, C, C, B
```

But what I receive is:

```
[(3 {name:"A"}), (2 {name:"B"}), (1 {name:"C"}), (2 {name:"B"})]
[(3 {name:"A"}), (1 {name:"C"}), (3 {name:"A"}), (2 {name:"B"})]
[(3 {name:"A"}), (1 {name:"C"}), (2 {name:"B"}), (2 {name:"B"})]
[(3 {name:"A"}), (1 {name:"C"}), (1 {name:"C"}), (2 {name:"B"})]
[(3 {name:"A"}), (3 {name:"A"}), (2 {name:"B"}), (2 {name:"B"})]
[(3 {name:"A"}), (3 {name:"A"}), (1 {name:"C"}), (2 {name:"B"})]
```

So the pathways I'm not getting are:

```
A, A, A, B
A, B, B, B
A, B, A, B
```

Does anyone have some insight?

Here it is in the console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=4srv4h

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one link from A to A, so it can only traverse A to A once. That's why you don't get A, A, A (or B, B, B)...

Similarly, you consume the A -> B relationship the first time you go between them, so you can't get A, B, A, B.

Finally, you can do `:REL*3` and leave off the `length(p) = 3`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks Wes. Do you know of any tricks to get the results I want? I'm trying to model a stochastic process that can enter previous states (nodes), and so it is desirable that my query can repeat relationships in its traversals.

If not then I guess I'll have to rethink this idea. :)

Comment: Do you know how long the path is like this? You can break it up with WITH. The reason the behavior is like this is to prevent infinite paths with cycles. Rels can only be traversed once.

Comment: The path length depends on the question I need to answer. In my post, it would be the question: given the process is in state A, in what ways can the process get to state B after three (3) time-steps.

And so I would want all pathways, including the pathways that are currently being omitted by my query, e.g. A -> A -> A -> B, since a process can stay in its current state with a certain probability.

I will play around with the WITH statement and do some more troubleshooting.

Comment: Ah I didn't see your solution in the console. Thanks - that looks like a solution to my problem for small traversals.

I will have to think about how I could achieve something like that with, say, 100 time-steps.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use Cypher's MATCH as it is currently implemented, but you could design a Java API-level program that could reuse relationships pretty easily. Ping me on twitter if you want help.